# Unable to run project on Docker from Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-for-windows, .net-core

So after many hours banging my head I decided to write.

I started a very simple console project on VS2022

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UserSecretsId>dfce778d-3821-42b2-af1a-b52233cd6dac</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm on Windows10 with a working Docker desktop running Linux containers

I've added linux container support on the project, pretty standard:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

The solution builds and launches a new docker container but fails to start with the following error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.4' (x64) was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.4&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

I've EXEC into the running container and installed some more .netcore related frameworks:

```
docker exec -it 3b083aa2ffc1066939c3083c5082d923a7a77aa72e816ebe3459f2d5af38aeab bash
root@3b083aa2ffc1:/app# dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.202
 Commit:    f8a55617d2

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  11
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.11-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.4
  Commit:  be98e88c76

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.202 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

What is wrong with this thing? Someone can help out troubleshooting this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The *dotnet/runtime* image does not contain an ASP.NET Core runtime. Not sure where your confusion comes from…?

Answer (score 0):

Replaced on the dockerfile the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
```

for

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

Still not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).